# Organizing a very large equation in boxes

Tags: equations, tikz-arrows

I have a very large equation that is collapsed in a very small notation. Something like

`f := a + b + c`

where

`a = a_1 + a_2 + a_n`

and

`a_1 = a_11 * ...`

and that goes on and on in a very large and not so simple equation/notation.

The equations are really not important in my question.

I would like to make a very large A3 poster to explore this equation. For the root node I would like to put something like

`\node (root) {f := a + b + c}`

and have some child like

`\node [rectangle,draw] (a) [below left = of root] { a = a_1 + a_2 + ...}`

And here is my question: I would like to  have a arrow coming from parameter `a` in `(root)` node pointing to the node box `(a)`.  Of course I can create a arrow from `(root)` node to `(a)` node, but this isn't what I want. I want the arrow coming from the `a` parameter.

How can I do it?

I also would love to hear tips to organize very large equations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case, that equation should be numbered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, positioning}
\tikzset{is/.style = {inner ysep=2pt}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{equation}
f :=  \tikzmarknode[is]{A}{a} + b + c
\end{equation}

    \bigskip
\tikzmarknode[draw, inner sep=1ex]{AA}{$a = a_1 + a_2 + \ldots$}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[->] (A) --  ++ (0,-0.5) -| (AA);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Option with use `flushright` for positioning of boxes with math expression(s) explanation and Ti*k*Z library `ext.paths.ortho`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,
                ext.paths.ortho,  % -|- and |-| path operations
                positioning}
\tikzset{is/.style = {inner ysep=2pt},
         ms/.style = {draw, inner sep=1ex, 
                      execute at begin node=\vphantom{$#1$}},
         ms/.default = f
         }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{equation}
f :=  \tikzmarknode[is]{A}{a} + \tikzmarknode[is]{B}{b} + c
\end{equation}
\begin{flushleft}\medskip
\tikzmarknode[ms]{AA}{$a = a_1 + a_2 + \dotsm$}
\tikzmarknode[ms]{BB}{$b = b_1 + b_2 + \dotsm$}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[->] (A) |-|[distance=2mm] (AA);
\draw[->] (B) |-|[distance=3mm] (BB);
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node (root) {$f := \subnode{roota}{a} + b + c$};
\node[rectangle, draw, below left=of root] (a) {$a = a_1 + a_2 + \ldots$};
\draw[->] (roota) -- +(0,-1) -| (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document};
```

[image: Two equations with arrow between]